# My app is not running with mobile data .its only run with wifi.and no error and exception is found

Tags: android

Below code runs with wifi but with mobile data it's not working:

**Here is my code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnlogin;
    TextView txtforgot;
    EditText edtpass,edtemail;
    public static final String TAG="inetzetta";
    private int result;
    boolean first_time;
    Constants constants;
    String stst,parent_email;
    private  String STATUS_CODE ;
    AppPreferences appPreferences;
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnlogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        txtforgot= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpass);
        edtemail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
        edtpass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        constants=new Constants();
        isConnected(LoginActivity.this);
        appPreferences=new AppPreferences(this);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((edtemail.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) && (edtpass.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)) {
                    edtemail.setError("Enter unique id");
                    edtpass.setError("Enter Password");
                }
                else if(edtemail.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    edtemail.setError("email field is empty");
                }
                else if(edtpass.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    edtpass.setError("password field is empty");
                }


              else  {

                    stst = (appPreferences.getString("statusinlogin", "Default_Value"));
                    new LoginAsync().execute(edtemail.getText().toString(), edtpass.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "ckeck,check..." + stst);


                }
            }
        });

        txtforgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgottPassword_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
/*Async for bacgroud task */
    public class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        HttpURLConnection conn= null;
        //JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        String jsonResp="";
        public String status;
        String token;
        String message;
        String parentid;
        String school_id;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            String email = params[0];
            String password=params[1];
            Log.d(TAG, "Doinbackground");

            try {
               URL url = new URL(constants.LOGIN +"unique_id=" + email + "&password=" + password );

                // U String cookies = CookieManager.getgetCookie(url);RL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.100:8080/parent_portal/index.php/parent_login/login?parent_email=" + email + "&password=" + password);
                conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                Log.d(TAG, "url connection");
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-   www-form-urlencoded");
               /* conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID=Sessionid");*/
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                //conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "input connection");

                Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("unique_id", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", password);


                String urlParameters=builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                Log.d(TAG, "BeforeOutputStream");
                DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "after dataoutput");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uEexc) {

                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught  : USE : "
                                + uEexc);
            }   catch (ConnectTimeoutException cTexc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in getconnection timeout : CTE : "
                                + cTexc);
            } catch (IOException iOexc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in io exception : IOE : "
                                + iOexc);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in exception : E : "
                                + exc);
            }
            try {

                Log.d(TAG,"before bufferedreader");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                Log.d(TAG,"after bufferedreader");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line ;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                reader.close();

                jsonResp = sb.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "result shows=" + jsonResp);


                jsonParam=new JSONObject(jsonResp);

            }catch(Exception exc){
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "Error in Api...  : "
                                + exc);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {

            status = jsonParam.getString("status");

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                JSONArray newJobj = jsonParam.getJSONArray("data");
              for (int i = 0; i < newJobj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject newjson = newJobj.getJSONObject(i);

            token = newjson.getString("Token");
            parentid = newjson.getString("parent_id");
            school_id = newjson.getString("school_id");
            parent_email = newjson.getString("Parent_Email");


            Log.d(TAG, "result shows=" + result);
            Log.d(TAG, "message " + message);
            Log.d(TAG, "token is " + token);
            status = jsonParam.getString("status");
            Log.d(TAG, "Printing status in async." + status);
            Log.d(TAG, "parend id from api" + parentid);
            Log.d(TAG, "parent email from async" + parent_email);


            appPreferences.putString("NameOfShared", token);
            appPreferences.putString("statuslogin", status);
            appPreferences.putString("parent_id", parentid);
            appPreferences.putString("parent_email", parent_email);
            appPreferences.putString("school_id", school_id);
            Log.d(TAG, "value of token" + token);
        }
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

          else if(status.equals("failure")){
                String str=jsonParam.getString("data");
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }}
                catch(Exception exc){
                     Log.i(TAG,
                "Error in Api...  : "
                    + exc);

                }

        }



    }


/*Mobile data connectivity*/
    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"my log for connectivity"+haveConnectedWifi);
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"my log for connectivity"+haveConnectedMobile);
        }
        return  haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;

    }

    private void showDialogMobile()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Connect to mobile data or wifi")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Connect to internet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                       /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
                        startActivity(intent);*/
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

              onBackPressedLogin();

       // super.onBackPressed();
}
    public void onBackPressedLogin() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                LoginActivity.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check in other device?

Comment: Hi Megha, welcome to SO. Consider trying to write us an ***[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)***

Comment: What error do you get??

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
    /**
     * Function for check network connection
     * @return : network connection status
     */
    private boolean networkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null)
            return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnlogin;
    TextView txtforgot;
    EditText edtpass,edtemail;
    public static final String TAG="inetzetta";
    private int result;
    boolean first_time;
    Constants constants;
    String stst,parent_email;
    private  String STATUS_CODE ;
    AppPreferences appPreferences;
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnlogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        txtforgot= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpass);
        edtemail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
        edtpass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
        constants=new Constants();

        appPreferences=new AppPreferences(this);

        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if ((edtemail.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) && (edtpass.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)) {
                    edtemail.setError("Enter unique id");
                    edtpass.setError("Enter Password");
                }
                else if(edtemail.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    edtemail.setError("email field is empty");
                }
                else if(edtpass.getText().toString().trim().length()==0)
                {
                    edtpass.setError("password field is empty");
                }
                else {

                    if(isConnected(LoginActivity.this)) {
                        stst = (appPreferences.getString("statusinlogin", "Default_Value"));
                        new LoginAsync().execute(edtemail.getText().toString(), edtpass.getText().toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "ckeck,check..." + stst);
                    } else {
                        showDialogMobile();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        txtforgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgottPassword_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
/*Async for bacgroud task */
    public class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
        HttpURLConnection conn= null;
        //JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        String jsonResp="";
        public String status;
        String token;
        String message;
        String parentid;
        String school_id;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


            String email = params[0];
            String password=params[1];
            Log.d(TAG, "Doinbackground");

            try {
               URL url = new URL(constants.LOGIN +"unique_id=" + email + "&password=" + password );

                // U String cookies = CookieManager.getgetCookie(url);RL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.100:8080/parent_portal/index.php/parent_login/login?parent_email=" + email + "&password=" + password);
                conn =(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                Log.d(TAG, "url connection");
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-   www-form-urlencoded");
               /* conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","JSESSIONID=Sessionid");*/
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                //conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                conn.connect();
                Log.d(TAG, "input connection");

                Uri.Builder builder=new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("unique_id", email)
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", password);


                String urlParameters=builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                Log.d(TAG, "BeforeOutputStream");
                DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "after dataoutput");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uEexc) {

                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught  : USE : "
                                + uEexc);
            }   catch (ConnectTimeoutException cTexc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in getconnection timeout : CTE : "
                                + cTexc);
            } catch (IOException iOexc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in io exception : IOE : "
                                + iOexc);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.i("",
                        "Error Caught in exception : E : "
                                + exc);
            }
            try {

                Log.d(TAG,"before bufferedreader");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                Log.d(TAG,"after bufferedreader");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line ;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                reader.close();

                jsonResp = sb.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "result shows=" + jsonResp);


                jsonParam=new JSONObject(jsonResp);

            }catch(Exception exc){
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "Error in Api...  : "
                                + exc);

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {

            status = jsonParam.getString("status");

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                JSONArray newJobj = jsonParam.getJSONArray("data");
              for (int i = 0; i < newJobj.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject newjson = newJobj.getJSONObject(i);

            token = newjson.getString("Token");
            parentid = newjson.getString("parent_id");
            school_id = newjson.getString("school_id");
            parent_email = newjson.getString("Parent_Email");


            Log.d(TAG, "result shows=" + result);
            Log.d(TAG, "message " + message);
            Log.d(TAG, "token is " + token);
            status = jsonParam.getString("status");
            Log.d(TAG, "Printing status in async." + status);
            Log.d(TAG, "parend id from api" + parentid);
            Log.d(TAG, "parent email from async" + parent_email);


            appPreferences.putString("NameOfShared", token);
            appPreferences.putString("statuslogin", status);
            appPreferences.putString("parent_id", parentid);
            appPreferences.putString("parent_email", parent_email);
            appPreferences.putString("school_id", school_id);
            Log.d(TAG, "value of token" + token);
        }
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

          else if(status.equals("failure")){
                String str=jsonParam.getString("data");
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }}
                catch(Exception exc){
                     Log.i(TAG,
                "Error in Api...  : "
                    + exc);

                }

        }



    }


/*Mobile data connectivity*/
    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    boolean haveNetworkConnected = false;
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (ni != null) {
        haveNetworkConnected = ni.isConnected();
    }
    return  haveNetworkConnected;
}

    private void showDialogMobile()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Connect to mobile data or wifi")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Connect to internet", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
                       /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
                        startActivity(intent);*/
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

              onBackPressedLogin();

       // super.onBackPressed();
    }
    public void onBackPressedLogin() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                LoginActivity.this);

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exit");

        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Do you really want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```